# Downloading ArcGIS Online data, and editing in ArcGIS as layers, not separate geodatabases?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, editing, feature-layer, download

**My goal:** I'm trying to download layers from ArcGIS Online and put them into ArcGIS Desktop (10.3.1) as layers and edit them. One is a feature layer, another is a hosted feature layer. Most of the information I want to use is in the feature layer that is **not** hosted.

**My problems:**

1. The feature layer that *isn't* hosted cannot be downloaded for use in ArcGIS, is it possible to change it to a hosted feature layer in an editable format (i.e. not a GDB  - see below), OR do I need to start over?

   - This is what opens when I download the map or the layers:

[image: Map layers as loaded from ArcGIS online, appear as several GDB's]

I have very little experience with ArcGIS Online, though I am familiar with ArcGIS (not python). I am the owner of all the layers and the administrator of the organization.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Are you the owner of the hosted and non-hosted feature layers?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, I am the owner of all the layers in the account.

Comment: 1. you want to edit the data separate to the original services and not sync the edits back?
2. Is this a repeatable process you want automated?
3. On the feature layer, jump into ArcGIS Server Manager --> service --> capabilities --> turn on 'sync'  Then add the layer to ArcMap and right click and export data to a local file geodatabase.

Comment: 1. I would like to edit the data separately. Desktop has a lot more functionality, I will likely upload the edited data when done. 2. No.

Answer (score 1):

On the feature layer, as you own the service, jump into the service settings and enable sync.

Then you will be able to right click layers in ArcMap and export data locally as per your requirements in the comments.

I would also suggest looking at editing the feature services directly in ArcMap where you can take a local copy offline for editing.

Comment: I don't know where to get to the service settings? I also only have ArcGIS for home use, the ArcGIS online data is owned by the non-profit, I have access to ArcGIS through a course.

Comment: None of this is enterpise membership, etc.

Comment: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that you own the layers in the account?

Comment: Yes, a previous volunteer added them. The link explains everything except how to change a feature layer to a hosted feature layer or combine the two layers. It's ok though, I will use what I've got and re-do the hosted feature layer with new edits. Thank you for your help.